# Потоки, реализация интерфейса Runnable (Шилдт)

Tags: java

```
class NewThread implements Runnable 
  Thread t;

  NewThread(){
    t = new Thread(this, "Демонстрационнный поток");
    System.out.println("Дочерний поток создан: " + t);
    t.start();
  }

    public void run(){
      try{
        for(int i=5;i>0;i--){
        System.out.println("Дочерний поток: " + i);
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }
      }catch (InterruptedException e){
         System.out.println("Дочерний поток прерван.");
      }
      System.out.println("Дочерний поток завершен.");
   }
}

class ThreadDemo{


  public static void main(String args[]){
    new NewThead();
    try{
       for(int i=5;i>0;i--){
          System.out.println("Главный поток: " + i);
          Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
         System.out.println("Главный поток прерван.");
    }
       System.out.println("Главный поток завершен.");
  }
}
```

ВОПРОС: помогите разобраться с этим кодом детально. Изучаю раздел многопоточное программирование (Шилдт), не могу понять что за чем просиходит (по какой схеме)?

Comment: советую тут почитать на тему http://habrahabr.ru/post/164487/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Будем исходить из того, что время от постановки потока в очередь (метод `start`) до его запуска (метод `run`) минимально (приравняем его к 10 мс). А временем всех операций будем пренебрегать, т.е. оно равно 0 мс (кроме метода `sleep` конечно). Сразу замечу, что в твоём коде нет причин, для падения исключения `InterruptedException`.

- 0 - запуск программы
- 0 - создание экземпляра `NewThread` (пусть будет объект `nt`)
- 0 - Создание потока внутри объекта `nt` (объект-поток `t`)
- 0 - Постановка в очередь на запуск потока `t` (вызов метода `start`)
- 0 - `System.out.println("Главный поток: " + i);`
- 10 - Запуск потока `t` из очереди (метод `run` объекта `nt`)
- 10 - `System.out.println("Дочерний поток: " + i);`
- 510 - `System.out.println("Дочерний поток: " + i);`
- 1000 - `System.out.println("Главный поток: " + i);`
- 1010 - `System.out.println("Дочерний поток: " + i);`
- 1510 - `System.out.println("Дочерний поток: " + i);`
- 2000 - `System.out.println("Главный поток: " + i);`
- 2010 - `System.out.println("Дочерний поток: " + i);`
- 2510 - `System.out.println("Дочерний поток завершен.");`
- 3000 - `System.out.println("Главный поток: " + i);`
- 4000 - `System.out.println("Главный поток: " + i);`
- 5000 - `System.out.println("Главный поток завершен.");`

Answer (score 3):

```
сlass NewThread implements Runnable // создаешь класс потоков, реализующий интерфейс Runnable 
  Thread t; // поле, хранящее поток экземпляра

  NewThread(){ // конструктор, не имеющий входных параметров 
    t.new Thread(this, "Демонстрационнный поток"); // ссылаешь поле класса на новый поток с именем "Демонстрационнный поток"
    System.out.println("Дочерний поток создан: " + t);
    t.start(); // запускаешь поток. Тут фишка в том, что когда ты создаешь экземпляр данного типа потока, он сразу же и стартует

    public void run(){ // Метод, описывающий инструкции, которые должен выполнить поток 
      try{ 
        for(int i=5;i>0;i--){
        System.out.println("Дочерний поток: " + i);
        Thread.sleep(500); // заставляешь текущий поток заснуть
      }
      }catch (InterruptedException e){ // здесь обрабатываешь исключение, лишь хотя бы потому что метод sleep возбудитель InterruptedException 
         System.out.println("Дочерний поток прерван.");
      }
      System.out.println("Дочерний поток завершен.");
   }
}

class ThreadDemo{


  public static void main(String args[]){
    new NewThead(); // запускаешь поток типа NewClass
    try{
       for(int i=5;i>0;i--){
          System.out.println("Главный поток: " + i);
          Thread.sleep(1000); // улаживаешь главный поток спать, дабы наглядно продемонстрировать параллельную работу потока типа NewThead и главного потока
    }catch (InterruptedException e){ 
         System.out.println("Главный поток прерван.");
    }
       System.out.println("Главный поток завершен.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, для чего this  в коде  t.new Thread(this, "Демонстрационнный поток")

Comment: @ya16 здесь this используется для передачи потока типа NewClass текущего экземпляра